# c# saving very large bitmaps as jpegs (or any other compressed format)

Tags: c#, stream, bitmap, compression, jpeg

I am currently handling very large images, which are basically generated by stitching together many smaller images (e.g. panorama or photo mosaic software). In order to avoid out-of-memory exceptions (in memory are only "maps" of how to arrange the smaller images), I wrote some code saving these images line by line as bitmaps using BinaryWriter and LockBits. So far, so good.

The problem is now that I would like to save these images as Jpegs (or PNGs) as well. Since I am pretty new to c# I can only think of two ways for now:

1) Similar to the bitmap saving procedure. Generating some jpeg header and saving the big images line by line, compressing them somehow before. I have no idea how to perform the compression though.

2) Streaming the already saved bitmap into the memory and saving it as encoded jpeg.

Since the second approach seemed easier, I tried something like this:

```
FileStream fsr =
    new FileStream("input.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FileStream fsw =
    new FileStream("output.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);

EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] =
    new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 80L);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(fsr);
bmp.Save(fsw, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
bmp.Dispose();
```

The problem is now that the save-method tries to completely load the bitmap into memory first, causing an out-of-memory exception.

I would be more than happy for any suggestions on how to solve or circumvent this problem!

Comment: OutOfMemoryException in this day and age? How large is your bitmap?

Comment: yes, you can run into memory problems easily, i was resizing about 10K images and running into `OutOfMemoryException` often, even though i was disposing properly.

Comment: OOM from a Bitmap is very suspect. This class will throw the memory exception for just about anything that goes wrong, including bad parameters etc.

Comment: Maybe this [.NET wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/freeimagecswrapper.aspx) for the [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/index.html) library might help you.

Comment: Does your approach work with a small bitmap? Test the code first.

Comment: Bitmap size could be sth like 25kpx x 25kpx easily. Just assume it is just below the 32kpx limit. Saving such a Bitmap on HDD gives you files the size of 1-2 GB.

Comment: This approach works for small images, but is loading the complete image into the memory. I will have a look into freeimage, but I would actually prefer to code some solution myself.

Comment: FreeImage does not seem to solve my problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that JPEG compression has some important non-trivial drawbacks :

1) JPEG is lossy, so you will not regenerate the same image. This might be perfectly acceptable, but if you need to exactly regenerate source image, then PNG is the way to go.

2) JPEG is aligned on 8-pixels boundaries. If you stich together images which sizes are not multiple of 8, either in width or height, you will get some strong artefacts at image boundaries

Considering your use case, i would rather recommend to **not** stitch images together, and use a standard compression algorithm, such as PNG or Zlib, on each smaller image. You can still store the resulting compressed streams into a single file. The advantage is that you can then directly "jump" at the position of the small image you want to extract, which will save * a lot * of memory.

The disadvantage is that you cannot "visually preview" all the smaller images into a big single one (you will need to create a program for this usage).

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot.

Changing the code into saving the big image not linewise but in chunks of 8x8px should be no problem. Also slight information loss due to saving it as jpeg does not matter.

My problem right now is, that I have absolutely no clue on how to write a jpeg (or png, for that matter) file blockwise.

Comment: If you want to stick with the "big image" method, I would rather recommend to save it in bands of 8 lines. Then you'll get in memory a bitmap of Width x 8 pixels, which will decrease memory requirement compared to the full image.

Comment: I just modified the code and am now saving the image in bands of 8 lines. But still there is the problem that I do not know how to save it as a jpeg: For bmps I wrote a header and then just streamed the ARGB byte values one by one. I would need some function, which can write a jpeg-header and then - this is what I consider to be the tricky part - encode the bands into the jpeg format and append them to the existing file chunk by chunk.

Comment: "Save" method is not suitable here, unfortunately, but maybe "SaveAdd" is (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tathhx27.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsyxs70s.aspx). Otherwise, you will need to manage directly the stream and use an external libray, such as FreeImage (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Comment: SaveAdd is only for multiframe images such as GIFs. I will have a look into FreeImage though, but I would actually like to stay independent from external libraries.

Comment: I just checked FreeImage but could not find any method on how to write JPGs chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can't do this in .NET, but you can always call into a C library to do the heavy lifting. I haven't used it myself, but I suggest you look at the [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) library. It's a C library with licensing that allows for both open source and commercial use and it looks like it might do what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it. But I would actually prefer to avoid extra libraries.

Comment: I checked out the GraphicsMagick lib but could not find anything on how to write jpegs (or pngs) in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

(since title says "or any other compressed format")

TIFF format has a notion of tiles and stripes. Both can be used to avoid having all the big image in memory at any time. Maybe tiles will come in handy for you since you are stitching small images.

You might try [LibTiff.Net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) (free, commercial-friendly, open-source, written in C# only) for the task.

There is an article [Basic introduction to the capabilities of the library](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/articles/KB/basic-introduction.html) with information about strip- and tile-oriented image IO (in the second part of the article).

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Do you know if there is any similar thing for jpegs, pngs, aso, too? Usually, I would always go for jpegs.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like this for JPEGs. Unfortunately, I don't know if there is anything like this for PNGs.