# c#: How to convert very large bitmaps

Tags: c#, stream, bitmap

I am currently dealing with very large bitmaps (32bit, > 1GB) close to the bitmap size limit (~ 32 kpx squared). For file storage reasons, I would like to convert these bitmaps into more suitable formats, e.g. jpg or png. But I have to convert them without loading the whole bitmap into memory at once, since I will get a out-of-memory error.

Is there any way how to convert the bitmap in parts, e.g. linewise, blockwise or bandwise? At the moment, I am using Photoshop for saving, but this is not an option at a later stage of the project anymore.

Thanks for the help,
Max

Comment: This is not a real answer to your question, so I am posting it as a comment: Do this conversion on a 64 bit machine with enough memory - you won't get an `OutOfMemoryException` this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# saving very large bitmaps as jpegs (or any other compressed format)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247996/c-sharp-saving-very-large-bitmaps-as-jpegs-or-any-other-compressed-format)

Comment: @ Daniel: Thanks, but this wont solve the problem, since .Net only allows about 1.2 GB of memory to be used independent of 32bit or 64bit machines.
@ Magnus: It is not a copy, but a more specific phrasing of the question, since a lot of the people did not understand the original issue.

Comment: I don't know if any suitable solution solves your issue because i don't think that there is any .NET image library which allows you to save a image onto disc while streaming the image data into the encoder. Maybe you've to do this by yourself and read a lot of documentation about the formats. ( Did this once, it's not funny, really! )

Comment: you may have to resort to c++ / c (or at least use a c++ / c library) and provide a c# interface around it

Comment: Give a try to an OpenCV wrapper, EmguCV [www.emgu.com].